# Retrieving the index of NaN in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, nan

I have a list like:

```
li = [nan, 'Grvl', 'Pave']
```

The two other item is a string but nan is not a variable. It is a *Not A Number* float.

```
type(li[0])
>> <class 'float'>
```

Now I wanted to be able to index nan by:

```
li.index(float('nan'))
```

But there was an error:

```
ValueError: nan is not in list
```

How do I get the index of nan? I'm using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that NaN != NaN, mathematically, so you can pass a generator to `next` to get the first index of NaN, or -1 if it doesn't exist.

```
nan_idx = next((i for i, v in enumerate(li) if v != v), -1)
```

```
print(nan_idx) 
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write generic custom function using [`math.isnan()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) to get the index of elements in the list with or without `NaN` values.

```
from match import isnan

def nan_index(my_list, el):
    if isinstance(el, float) and isnan(el):
        for i, e in enumerate(my_list):
            if isnan(e):
                return i
        else:
            raise ValueError
    else:
        return my_list.index(el)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> nan_index([1, 2, 4, 5], 4)  # For list of numbers 
2

>>> nan_index(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'b')  # For list of strings
1

>>> nan_index([1, 2, 4, float('nan')], float('nan'))  # For list with `NaN`
3

>>> nan_index([1, 2, 4, 5], float('nan'))  # "ValueError", for list without match
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in nan_index
ValueError
```